# Workers in Apache Flex 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

has anyone been able to use Workers in AIR Application built with Flex 4.9.1 and AIR 3.7? 
I wanted to give it a try for a project, but as soon as I include/setup the worker like in the tutorial made by Lee Brimelow, my Application "freezes". Which means: It does not start. The compiler compiles, I get the info-text in the console, but neither my window opens nor my does any of my events get fired.

Ideas anyone :) ?

Comment: Is this for desktop? You can't use Workers for mobile or TV projects. I'm unsure if it will compile or not, but it's worth making sure this is a desktop project before moving forward.

Comment: Yepp, Desktop. The confusing thing is, there is no error or something else. Simply NOTHING happens :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple solution. Simply add

```
-swf-version=XX //XX must be >=17
```

as a compiler argument and it works. I think this is a bit weird, since I am using AIR 3.7 but okay, whatever it takes :)